# Change default login page endpoint spring boot admin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

Working on deploying Spring Boot Admin behind ngnix with security enabled. Ngnix configuration expose a /monitoring endpoint that is mapped to the SBA instance (Full url is then [www.domain.com/monitoring](http://www.domain.com/monitoring)). When trying to reach this endpoint it redirects me to /login which is not handled by Ngnix (Full Url of redirection is: [www.domain.com/login](http://www.domain.com/login)).

Solution that I tried:

- Ngnix configuration on /login to redirect to the instance (not working)
- Spring security configuration update to redefine login page endpoint /monitoring/login (not working, returning 404)

Any idea on how to solve this is very appreciated.

--Update:

WebSecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    private final AdminServerProperties adminServer;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler =
                new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("redirectTo");
        successHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(this.adminServer.getContextPath() + "/monitoring");

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(this.adminServer.getContextPath() + "/assets/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(this.adminServer.getContextPath() + "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(this.adminServer.getContextPath() + "/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage(this.adminServer.getContextPath() + "/login")
                .successHandler(successHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl(this.adminServer.getContextPath() + "/logout")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
               .ignoringRequestMatchers(
                       new AntPathRequestMatcher(this.adminServer.getContextPath() +
                               "/instances", HttpMethod.POST.toString()),
                       new AntPathRequestMatcher(this.adminServer.getContextPath() +
                               "/instances/*", HttpMethod.DELETE.toString()),
                       new AntPathRequestMatcher(this.adminServer.getContextPath() + "/actuator/**"))
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .key(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(1209600);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your spring security configuration attempt code

Comment: Updated the question with webSecurityConfig. You can see it's pretty the same as in the documentation from SBA project, except for the success handler

Comment: shouldn't you (just) `permitAll()` (additionally) on `.../monitoring/*`? (in contrast to "sba quickstart")

Comment: the behavior described conforms with your config: `.../monitoring` requires authentication (due to `.anyRequest().authenticated()`), thus forwards you to `/login`.

Comment: Will try it and get back to you. Thanks for pointing it out ;)